# Mapping java.awt.Color in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

Right now I have the following attribute in one of domain objects:

```
 @Column(name = "color")
 public Color getColor() {
    return color;
 }
```

The field is stored in text in the Postgres DB. When I try to store these I get the following exceptions:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:53)
at ...
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5C786163
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
at ...
```

I was wondering if Hibernate offers any mapping of this type? The other possibility I have is to convert the Color into a String using the RGB values. But since my domain objects are also my Hibernate objects I don't really know how I should do that without changing the type of the attribute to String.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I noticed I can write an own converter using javax.persistence.AttributeConverter, as described [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)